# Angular: Show or hide elements without effecting element spacing

Tags: html, css, angular

I have a row of divs that contain information such as the brand name and image. If a brand has a name I would like to display it else leave it blank. The problem is not all products have brand name.I want to keep the spacing the consistent regardless of the fact if there is a name or not.

I already tried ngIf and the hidden directive but both do not have the desired result.

```
<div  *ngFor="let product of products">
    <h5 class="product-brandname" [hidden]="!product.brandname">{{product.brandname}}</h5>
   <img/>
   etc...
</div>
```

https://www.dropbox.com/s/ucs51qugchvfxso/Screen%20Shot%202019-01-28%20at%202.03.48%20PM.png?dl=0

Comment: What would be an acceptable answer? Filling, spacing, pushing, margins, padding, offsetting or styling? Please update the question to explain what kind of answer would be accepted so people don't waste their time giving multiple correct answers.

Answer (score 2):

To make sure that the `h5` element does not collapse, set an unbreakable space as the defaut value:

```
<h5 class="product-brandname">{{ product.brandname || "&nbsp;" }}</h5>
```

If you really want to hide empty `h5` elements that still occupy the same space, set their style [visibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/visibility) attribute to `hidden`. In that case, the default text can be any non-empty string:

```
<h5 class="product-brandname" [style.visibility]="product.brandname ? 'visible' : 'hidden'">
  {{ product.brandname || "Any text" }}
</h5>
```

See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cyujgt?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) for a demo.

Comment: What you're saying doesn't add up. An element with a space in it is rendered. From what OP says it looks like they're using flexbox which will output the same result with `&nbsp;`. That's why I suggested they provide a [mcve]. We're both kind of in the wrong for answering without one... :)

Comment: I updated the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cyujgt?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) to show the different outputs with `&nbsp;` and with a normal space, and with different `visibility` style attributes.

Comment: Thanks, `[style.visibility]="myVar ? 'visible' : 'hidden'"`    does the job well